# "<<" operand doesn't work with an array of string in visual studio2012

Tags: c++, c++11, cppcheck

This is the class "Date.h"

```
class Date
{
    private: 
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;

    public:         
        void PrintDateV2();
        Date(int, int, int);
        ~Date();

};
```

This is "Date.cpp" with the implementation of the specified function that doesnt work

```
void Date::PrintDateV2()
{
    string months[12]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",           "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
   /*line of error*/cout << months[month-1] << endl;//<< ":: " << day << ", " << year << endl;
}
```

this is the error in visual studio in error list:

> no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are: std::basic_ostream char, std::char_traits> << std::string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot

```
#include <string>
```

in your program before using `operator<<`.

Comment: @jxh i try to let content stand on its own insted of relying of presentation to get upvotes

Comment: Meh. I see it as rewarding for a correct answer. But good point-- I should get some credit for fixing the answer.

Comment: @Kal: I don't know... it seems more like you're just trying to get an early, quick answer without paying the cost of four extra characters. If that's not upvote scamming, what is? ;-)

Comment: @Kal: Both are important, because a clear presentation is a clear answer.